# Application of the chain rule for curves

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, self-learning

> **Problem**: Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $$y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y,z) -x \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y,z) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x,y,z) \geq a>0, \forall(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \tag{*} $$
>   Let $\gamma: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}^3$ a differentiable curve given by $\gamma(t)=(- \cos t, \sin t ,t), \ t \geq 0$
>
> Show for $g(t):=f(\gamma(t))$ that $\lim_{t \to + \infty} g(t) = + \infty$

**My approach**: My idea was to make use of the fact that $g$ is differentiable and the derivative is given by $$g'(t)=< \nabla f(\gamma(t)), \dot\gamma(t)> $$ because the result will very much look like (*), if I can manage to show that $g'(t)\geq a >0$ it would follow that for all $t\geq 0$ I have that $g$ is strictly monotone increasing, if I then could prove that there exists no upper bound, this would finish the exercise.

I have $\dot \gamma(t)=(\sin t, \cos t ,1)$, my next step was to compute $g'(t)$, I obtained that $$g'(t)= \sin t \frac{\partial f( \gamma(t))}{\partial x}+ \cos t \frac{\partial f ( \gamma(t))}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f(\gamma(t))}{\partial z} $$
Which looks a lot like (*), however not quite, because there is this annoying minus sign missing, which might be due to a typing error in C. Michels Analysis II Exercises.

Also I fail to make sense of the partial derivatives above, I left the $x,y,z$ in place in order to establish the connection with (*), however if I naively substitute $x= - \cos t, y = \sin t, z = t$ I get very weird partial derivatives that make no sense at all to me.

Is my approach to this exercise (in general) right? Or did I misguide myself into trap because (*) looks so much like the chain rule for curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct and you have done all the work. You got confused with a sign, but note that signs are exactly the ones you need.

Note that you have

$$g'(t)= \sin t \frac{\partial f( \gamma(t))}{\partial x}+ \cos t \frac{\partial f ( \gamma(t))}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f(\gamma(t))}{\partial z}\ge a >0.$$

Why? Because $(x,y,z)=(-\cos t,\sin t,t).$ That is,

$$\sin t \frac{\partial f( \gamma(t))}{\partial x}+ \cos t \frac{\partial f ( \gamma(t))}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f(\gamma(t))}{\partial z}$$

$$=y \frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x}-x \frac{\partial f (x,y,z)}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial z}.$$

Comment: Thank you a lot, I've been staring at these equations for far too long and didn't think about that at all. If the question is okay, by 'done all the work' you mean that this is sufficient to show that $g$ converges to infinity? Because in my head it feels like I should show that $g$ is unbounded.

Comment: Note that $g'(t)\ge a\implies g(t)-g(0)=\int_0^tg'(s)ds\ge at.$ That is, $g(t)\ge g(0)+at, \forall t>0.$ Thus, since $a>0$ it follows that $\lim_{t\to \infty} g(t)=\infty.$